# Universal property of the Abel map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

In the book [Algebraic Geometry I edited by Safarevich](http://books.google.com/books?id=-QMWR-x66XUC&printsec=frontcover), the following universal property of the Jacobian variety of an algebraic curve is given page 158 (with no more details):

> The Abel mapping $a: C\to J(C)$ is universal: for any regular map $f: C\to A$ into an abelian variety $A$, there exists a unique regular homomorphism $F: J(C)\to A$ such that $F\circ a=f$.

Suppose that $C$ is a compact Riemann surface. Then $J(C)$ is isomorphic as a group to $\text{Pic}^0(C)$. Pick a base point $P_0\in C$. The Abel mapping is
$$P\to [P-P_0].$$
We can see what $F$ should be:

- Assuming the existence of $F$, we would have 
  $$F([E-dP_0])=\sum n_if(P_i)$$
  if $E=\sum n_iP_i$ is an effective divisor of degree $d$.
- Pick an integer $r\ge g$. By Riemann-Roch, any divisor class $[D]$ of degree zero contains an effective divisor $E$ of degree $g$: $[D]=[E-rP_0]$. Thus we would finally have
  $$F([D])=F([E-rP_0])$$
  which defines $F$ everywhere.

**However, I can't see how this could be well-defined**.

In the second step, we would like to be able to pick $r$ so that $\dim L(D+rP_0)=1$, but is this even possible ?

Comment: For each $D$, you can find a such $r$. But you wouldn't be able to prove $F$ is additve. So you need a uniform integer $r$ as in answer_bot's answer. Then you lose the condition on the dimension of $L(D+rP_0)$, this is reason why you need extra works to show the independence on $E$ as again in the proof of answer_bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a fun question. To prove you thing is well defined consider the morphism
$$
C^n = C \times \ldots \times C \longrightarrow A,\quad
(p_1, \ldots, p_n) \longmapsto \sum f(p_i)
$$
This clearly factors through the symmetric power $S^n(C) = C^n/S_n$ giving a morphism $f^n : S^n(C) \to A$. Since C is a smooth curve, this symmetric power is a smooth projective variety too. In fact $S^n(C)$ is the moduli space of effective divisors of degree $n$ on $C$. If $n > 2g + 99$, then through every point $D$ of $S^n(C)$ there is a projective space passing through, namely the linear system $|D|$. To see that your map is well defined we have to show that $f^n$ maps each of these $|D|$ to a point.

To do this it certainly suffices to show that any morphism $f : \mathbf{P}^1 \to A$ is constant. Now taking $C = \mathbf{P}^1$ in the discussion above, we see that if $f$ is not constant, then we get for every $n$ a nonconstant map $\mathbf{P}^n = S^n(\mathbf{P}^1) \to A$. To finish the proof by contradiction one has just to do the following

**Exercise:** If $X$ is a variety of dimension $< n$, then every morphism $\mathbf{P}^n \to X$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you! I'd have the following question: Why did you pick $n>2g+99$ ? Wouldn't $n=g$ suffice to get $L(D+rP_0)$ nonzero ?

Comment: Dear answer_bot: in my opinion the beautiful result in your last line is  too difficult  to be left as  an exercise.